# I need to make a create-a-class system like in COD

Tags: c#, graphics-programming

I need to make a  create-a-class system like in COD but I don't know what code I need. I am also wondering if I have to make a photoshop image for every way it could look or do I type in the code to load a certain image.

Comment: Fully spec out the feature set you need, then your questions will have answers.

Answer (score 0):

In your player class you would need say 3 power up classes declared, in your constructor for your class you could set them as default power ups. Then in the player class you would need a get and set method, a get method to return the current power ups and set method to set them.

For your actual powerups just have an image stored in the class and draw that when you create the class object.